# StateChart Diagram Angular Component

Tags: user-interface, components, editor, angular7, diagram

I need a UI library with Angular components to display and edit state chart diagrams with data bindings, so the diagrams can be translated bidirectional between the visual diagram and the native statemachine model entities in my application. I have pored over pages of google search to no avail.

I must admit I am a newbie to Angular and my expertise is to the level of using standard components available from npmjs repository. So far, I have been comfortable using different ui components such as ngx-bootstrap, valour, etc. I do not have the competence or know-how to build new components using diagram libraries with JS/JQuery inside my angular project to realise the requirements. I would really appreciate if any UI Toolkit/Library available for this. Even reasonably priced commercial frameworks are acceptable for me.

Thanks in advance for any help.

I have already checked out free/open-source/commercial frameworks such as Telerik Kondo, SyncFusion, Ionic, JQWidgets, etc. I have pored over their documentation published for free. However, I always end up in either (a) they do not suit my needs, or (b) it involves developing this component myself. I know how it sounds, but my need is similar to needing a car; not design & build one myself. I do not have the ability to do it.

I need support for Angular 7 or 8 to be precise.